# ¿Cómo miro la version de python en CMD de windows?

Tags: python

¿Que tengo que hacer para mostrar la versión de *Python* escribiendo `python --version` en el *CMD*?

Comment: Con `python --version` o simplemente escribe `python` en la consola y la primera línea que aparece es la versión. No das mas detalles, pero es muy común que esté `python` en tu ruta, por lo que tendrías que escribir la ruta completa: `q:\la\ruta\completa\a\python --version`. Pero en realidad estoy adivinando. Lee esta guía [ask] y edita tu pregunta con los detalles faltantes.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es añadir a la variable de entorno path la ruta donde esté tu python instalado

Comment: añadí el path y me funciono muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Dentro del interprete, en ejecución.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

[link de referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script)

Answer (score 1):

1. Windows + R.
2. Escribes Python

Se aperturará un interprete de python y en la primera linea te mostrará que versión de python tienes, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar en la línea de comandos del CMD **python --version** te mostrará la versión de Python instalada en tu equipo.

Answer (score 0):

En Windows 11 no te sale , si escribes solo python --version , te sale PS C:\Users\Daniel> python --version
No se encontr¾ Python; ejecuta sin argumentos para instalar desde Microsoft Store o deshabilita este acceso directo en Configuraci¾n > Administrar alias de ejecuci¾n de la aplicaci¾n.

y si abres pones desde CMD como Administrador te sale asi

C:\Windows\system32>python --version
No se encontr¾ Python; ejecuta sin argumentos para instalar desde Microsoft Store o deshabilita este acceso directo en Configuraci¾n > Administrar alias de ejecuci¾n de la aplicaci¾n.

, si solo pones Python , te direcciona al Microsoft store
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi caso yo descargue el Python desde la pagina oficial de python.org , no se como se solucionara , pero al menos se que lo tengo instalado

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```bash
py --version
```

Me pasó lo mismo en Windows 11

Comment: También verifica que tengas en el path de las variables de sistemas la ruta a donde esta instalado Python.